Twilio X Signature validation fails for the webhook request
I have configured webhook url in twilio and a springboot app with POST Api listening to it. I am tryin to validate the X-Twilio-Signature received in the header by passing the eurl request body (string) and signature to com.twilio.security.RequestValidator.validate  method. But i am always getting false returned
validate(String url, String body, String expectedSignature)
I tried by changing string req body to MAP<string,string>. That also did not work

I have found this Twilio blog article which explains how you can validate the signature using Java and Spring boot
https://www.twilio.com/en-us/blog/secure-twilio-webhooks-java
This does use interceptors but the supporting repo https://github.com/mjg123/ValidatingTwilioWebhooks/blob/7df95b9ab80b53689ff79ff9d4a639b9ce03557b/src/main/java/com/twilio/requestverification/TwilioValidationHandlerInterceptor.java#L75 shows the body is manipulated prior to validating the signature.
Hope this helps

Spot on. Thanks! I missed to URLDecoder.decode and form a map. I was getting an encoded payload. So I have to decode and send the map to validate method.

(Turning jvx23's comment into an answer.)
I spent way too much time trying to figure out why the validation was failing, including tracing through the python helper libraries and watching it build the param strings, compute the signatures and compare the signatures.
The issue for me was the url-encoded body of the post.  Once I urldecoded it (urllib.parse.unquote_plus) before building the parms dictionary, the validator worked.

You are aware of the need for the commenting privilege, which you do not have. You know the rule ( https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). In that situation, please do not decide to misuse a different mechanism, an answering post, for what it is not meant for and which you are not yet allowed to do. But if you turn an existing comment into an answer then make that clear and it is fine.
